# What does MYSQL mean in the following code?

Tags: php

What does `MYSQL` mean in the following code.

```
require_once (MYSQL);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks to me like MYSQL is a constant. Look for something like this:

```
define('MYSQL', '/some/path/');
```

to get the 'real' include.

Comment: or, you can try to `echo MYSQL;` to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely a constant defined via `define()`.

Answer (score 1):

`MYSQL` would be a constant, defined by somewhere saying:

```
define("MYSQL", "/path/to/the/mysql/file.php");
```

Then, when they go to include/require it, it takes the defined path, and include/requires it.

Answer (score 1):

It's (almost assuredly) referring to a constant that's [`define()`](https://www.php.net/define)d elsewhere.